# Palindrome Partitioning DP complexity issue on memorization step

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

I have the following problem:

> Given a string s, partition s such that every substring of the
>   partition is a palindrome.
>
> Return the minimum cuts needed for a palindrome partitioning of s.

I got the correct solution but I am missing an optimization step, more particularly the memorization step needed in DP.

```
public int minCut(String a)   {
    if (isValidPal(a)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return minCut(a, 0, 0);
}
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int minCut(String a, int cut, int index) {
    // too many cuts already
    if(cut >= min) return min;
    // out of index
    if (index >= a.length()) {
        // what is left is a pal
        if (isValidPal(a)) {
            min = Math.min(min, cut);
            return cut;
        }
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    int newCut = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (isValidPal(a.substring(0, index + 1))) {
        // then cut
        newCut = minCut(a.substring(index + 1), cut + 1, 0);
    }
    // continue either way
    newCut = Math.min(minCut(a, cut, index + 1), newCut);
    return newCut;
}
HashMap<String, Boolean> memo  = new HashMap<>();
private boolean isValidPal(String s) {
    if(memo.containsKey(s)) {
        return memo.get(s);
    }
    boolean result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1)) {
            result =  false;
            break;
        }
    }
    memo.put(s, result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Assuming DP = Dynamic Programming.  You might want to spell that out though as the acronym is pretty short and not all that wide-spread in use.

Comment: There are a lot of explanations to this exact question here https://discuss.leetcode.com/category/140/palindrome-partitioning-ii

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a memo to store the results of your computations , assuming your algorithm is correct this should do the optimization

```
Map<String, Integer> dp = new HashMap<>();
private int minCut(String a, int cut, int index) {
// too many cuts already
if(cut >= min) return min;
String key = cut + " " + index;
//test if the memo contains the answer if yes return it

if(dp.containsKey(key)) return dp.get(key);
// out of index
if (index >= a.length()) {
    // what is left is a pal
    if (isValidPal(a)) {
        min = Math.min(min, cut);
        return cut;
    }
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
int newCut = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
if (isValidPal(a.substring(0, index + 1))) {
    // then cut
    newCut = minCut(a.substring(index + 1), cut + 1, 0);
}
// continue either way
newCut = Math.min(minCut(a, cut, index + 1), newCut);

//put the computed answer in the memo table
dp.put(key, newCut);
return newCut;
```

}

Comment: Hi Medhi, the key is wrong unfortunately. Because it will not try other better cut thus making the response incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sorry but my answer was based on the fact that your code is correct , here is a working example of a min palindrom partitioning with memoization

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {

  static HashMap<String, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();
  static String s;

  static int f(int i, int j){
    if(i == j) return 0;
    if(isPalindrom(s.substring(i, j))) return 0;
    String key = i + " " + j;
    if(memo.containsKey(key)) return memo.get(key);
    int ans = 999999;
    for(int k = i; k < j; k++){
      ans = Math.min(ans, f(i, k) + f(k + 1, j) + 1);
    }
    memo.put(key, ans);
    return ans;

  }
  static boolean isPalindrom(String s){
    return s.equals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    s = "aaka";
    System.out.println(f(0, s.length()));
  }
}
```